# Do additional overclocks improve performance?

Tags: bloons-td-5

In Bloons TD5, I noticed that I can overclock the same tower as many times as I want. Do the additional overclocks improve the tower's performance higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiki, Overclock does not stack.

***[SOURCE](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Overclock)***